# Apk expansion for money with choice to download

Tags: android, android-pay, apk-expansion-files

I want to add **non-free apk expansion** for my **free android application**. Also I want to give customer, who paid for my app, a choice: **download or not** this expansion *(it requires a lot of memory)*.

I have read a lot about expansions. But didnt find nesessary information about my question. I guess that expansion **starts downloading** when **user adds** application from Play Market, and it **will not ask** for permission to download big expansion (**!**) Will it be a problem?

UPD: From official google tutorial:

> Most of the time, Google Play downloads and saves your expansion files at the same time it downloads the APK to the device. However, in some cases Google Play cannot download the expansion files or the user might have deleted previously downloaded expansion files.

How can i forbid expansion to download from PlayMarket? (Only if user wants)